# Performing SQL "in" equivalent in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have two rateable objects `E` and `S`, S is contained within E so you say E.S and they both use the same object `R` to be rated; R will always have ONLY ONE rated object at a time so if `R.E.HasValue == true` then `R.S.HasValue` will never be true.

I have all the R objects from the database and I have E. What would be the lambda expression to get all Rs Where R.S in E.S??

---

**UPDATE** 
I found this [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317.aspx#RefNonScalarClosures) where it says:

> Referencing a non-scalar variables,
>   such as an entity, in a query is not
>   supported. When such a query executes,
>   a NotSupportedException exception is
>   thrown with a message that states
>   "Unable to create a constant value of
>   type EntityType. Only primitive types
>   ('such as Int32, String, and Guid')
>   are supported in this context."

So... I can't use A-Dubb's answer since the query reads

```
R.Where(r => r.SID.HasValue).Where(r => E.S.Contains(r.S))
```

Which results in a `NotSupportedException`... I still have the property `R.SID` which is of type `int?` but how could I then query all E.S to get their IDs?

**P.S.** E.S. is of type EntityCollection.

Comment: If you modeled this scenario in C#, that'd help. Your abstract is a little verbose, thus preventing it from seamlessly painting a concrete picture in the mind.

Comment: I know but sadly I can't get into much detail...

Comment: is this the object structure you're using?
object r
{
 E? x
 S? y 
}
object E
{
 object S
 {
 }
}

Comment: Write this query using SQL, so we can understand your needs.

Comment: @polishchuk `SELECT * FROM R WHERE R.S IN (SELECT S FROM E WHERE E.ID = id)` but in EF I already have all the Ss I need since `E` is an instance and I can call `E.S`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will say that IN clauses are normally represented with call to Contains. For example

```
public class R {
   public int Id {get; set;}
}

public IEnumerable<R> InClause(IEnumerable<int> ids) {
   var subset = ids.ToList();

   return dbContext.Query<R>.Where(r => subset.Contains(r.Id));
}
```

I know that's not the exact API call in EF, but it should help set the basis for your solution. Maybe you already know how to generate IN clauses but I figure if you did then you presumably wouldn't be stuck. If the IN clause isn't the difficult part of the query then what is? Maybe the piece of business logic you mentioned? Again, a C# object model would help.

Comment: You probably don't need to use subset, you can call Contains directly on ids and LINQ to Entities will parse it to SQL.

Comment: That's cool. I'm working more with NH these days so am not familiar with the more intricate details of EF. At least he knows how to do IN clause now. Just need to figure out the rest (the real problem we need to solve here).

Comment: This line: `R.Where(r => r.SID.HasValue).Where(r => E.S.Contains(r.S))` throws System.NotSupportedException. It reads "Unable to create a constant value of type 'S'. Only primitive types are supported in this context."

Comment: You cannot use contains on entities you must first get enumeration of Ids from `E.S` and after that use `ids.Contains(r.SID)`. Btw. quality of your question is terrible.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using contains though, is that its closer to sql "like" than "in".  So if you have user entry on say 8 digit ID's and someone
 enters 0 then contains will bring you back ALL id's with zero somewhere in it.